# Stackoverflow error on android using scala parsers

Tags: android, parsing, scala

How is it possible to get a stackoverflowerror using scala parsers in Android?
I was using this code:

```
val parseEApply: Parser[EApply] =
    ("EApply" ~> "(" ~> parseExpression) ~ ("," ~> parseListExpression <~ ")") ^^ {
  case e ~ l => EApply(e, l)
}
```

By rewriting it using different parenthesis, I got rid of the error. Can someone explain me why ?
EApply is an expression that can contain other expressions, and a list of expressions.

```
val parseEApply: Parser[EApply] =
     "EApply(" ~> parseExpression ~ ("," ~> parseListExpression <~ ")") ^^ {
  case e ~ l => EApply(e, l)
}
```

So why there might be a recursion error in the first and not in the second?

Comment: I don't know scala, but StackOverflowErrors are usually caused by too many levels of recursion in a recursive method call. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: what is the definition of parseExpression?

Comment: It's a parser that invoke a lot of different parsers in a disjunction, including parseEApply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to partially solve the problem by regrouping parsers in pairs. So instead of:

```
val parseExpression = p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | p6 | p7 | p8
```

I wrote it with parentheses

```
val parseExpression = ((p1 | p2) | (p3 | p4)) | ((p5 | p6) | (p7 | p8))
```

And it worked without complaints.